# Map Annotations Displayed on Date

Tags: ios, date, dictionary, annotations

I have a map that displays an array of annotations. These annotations are all called from a plist and each have a date at which they occur. I would like these annotations to display only on the date that they happen, however I have no clue how to approach this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
for (NSString *dateString in contentArray) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Date"];
}
```

This is the little bit of code I have written in but it does not solve anything for me.

EDIT:
Here is the code that calls the annotations generally.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    indexValue = 0;
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mapAddress" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intID];
    NSLog(@"array : %@",[dict objectForKey:strID]);
    [contentArray removeAllObjects];
    [contentArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:strID]];
    [contentArray retain];
    [self zoomToUserLocation:mapViewuno.userLocation];
}
- (void)zoomToUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (!userLocation)
        return;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(.5, .5);
    region = [mapViewuno regionThatFits:region];
    [mapViewuno setRegion:region animated:YES];
    counter = 0;

    [mapViewuno removeAnnotations:mapViewuno.annotations];

    if([contentArray count] != 0)
    {
        for(indexValue = 0; indexValue<[contentArray count];indexValue++)
        {
            FirstAnnotation *obj=[[FirstAnnotation alloc]init];

            obj.latitude = [[[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"lattitude"] floatValue];
            obj.longitude = [[[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];

            obj.titleName=[[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Title"];

            obj.Address = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Address"];

            obj.Phone = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Phone"];

            obj.intTag = indexValue;
            [mapViewuno addAnnotation:obj];
        }
        if ([mapViewuno.annotations count] == 0) return;

        //        [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, you remove existing annotations then add only the ones that meet your criteria from contentArray (eg. content.date equals "today"). Does contentArray really contain strings or something else like dictionaries?  Show the code that you currently have that adds the annotations from contentArray (add it to the Question).

Comment: You should start by putting an NSLog right before the FirstAnnotation alloc+init that shows the date for the current indexValue from contentArray.  For example: `NSLog(@"contentArray[%d] date = %@", indexValue, [[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] objectForKey:@"Date"]);` (assuming the date field's key is "Date").  Show the results for the first few NSLogs.